# clion disable code insight in certain files

Tags: clion

Is there any way to disable code insight in Clion for only one file in the project?

I have a swig file with just a few lines. But every time when I go into the file clion complains about header and freeze for long time. I have to open this file in phpstorm or other editor which can't parse c++.

[complain messages from Clion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKq3t.png)

```
//anal.swig
%module anal
%{
#include "anal.cpp"
%}
void anal(char *str, int size);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are several ways to do it:
  1. Change the file extension from ".h/.cpp" to ".templ" (non C++ related)
  2. Clion has [special IDE macros](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/02/clion-2017-1-eap-debugger-fixes-ide-macros-and-new-cmake/), so you can add guard

```
#ifndef __CLION_IDE__
//anal.swig
%module anal
%{
#include "anal.cpp"
%}
#endif
void anal(char *str, int size);
```

3. CLion has [`#pragma ide diagnostic ignored`](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206606565-How-to-configure-CLion-to-insert-GCC-pragmas-instead-of-clang-pragmas-) for selective switch off.